# Subpages in Menu Editor not Nesting

Tags: menus

I am building a website for a public school district.  All of our school buildings have common pages with the same name (i.e. Library, Nurse, Attendance, etc) that are nested under their parent building's page.  While trying to update our site navigation, I've noticed that for some reason the Menus -> Pages -> View All area is not nesting the building pages under their building and is instead listing them alphabetically.

[image: Pages not nesting]

The odd thing is, I have nested pages set up in other areas of the site and they *do* nest themselves on the list.
[image: Pages that are nesting]

Am I missing something? I can't find anything different about the way I nested the pages that do display properly vs those that don't.  I double checked the nested pages and they have their building listed as their parent.

I find this extremely frustrating.  Unless I go in and edit all of the pages under a specific building to force them into the recent list I have no idea which page is which.

- I do NOT want to add the building name to each page title.
- These pages are nested 3 levels deep (Schools -> Building Name -> Page Name)

If there isn't a way to fix the way the list displays, is there maybe a way to add the parent page's name to the page name?  Or another way to build the menus?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is just a limit of pagination. If a parent and grandparent can't fit on the same page of results, the grandchildren can't really be indented to pages that aren't showing.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I don't think that is what is happening.  None of the pages that are nested under these pages are appearing as children.  All of those library listings are on the same page as their parents.

Comment: It makes no difference the 'depth' of the nesting. When you are viewing the menu, it will show the nested pages if they are nested in their settings. (Like open the page and define it's parent). The really weird part is that the structures is showed at some parts. Can you specify where it's working and where it isn't?

Comment: There's hardly any rhyme or reason to it.  Most (but not all) second level nesting displays but none of the third level nesting displays.  For example, all of our school buildings are nested under "Schools" and only two of the buildings out of 8 display as such.  The rest are listed as if they do not have a parent.  All of the pages nested under each of the schools display as first level.  To test I added a 3rd level page to a section that is displaying nestings properly and it does not display with it's parent.

Comment: Since they weren't displaying properly anyway I deleted the Library page listed under each of my school buildings and now the 3rd level page I was testing with is displaying correctly under it's parent.  So it's almost like maybe it has to do with the number of pages being nested on the list or something.  It seems to nest the top half of the listing correctly and then just gives up (and it isn't even alpha order at that point)

Comment: @JacobPeattie  You were actually write about the pagination.  The pages that weren't nesting were all children of a page that starts with S ("Schools")  so almost all of the children appeared on an earlier page.  Once I realized that was the problem I found a bug report all about it that has been open for 6 years (https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18282).  If you want to submit an answer I'll mark it correct and add what I ended up doing to remove pagination all together to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who run into this in the future, the issue was due to pagination and the parent appearing on a different page than the children.  Removing pagination from the View All menu fixed the nesting.

There is a [ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18282) opened 7 years ago reporting this bug and it has yet to be resolved.  In the comments user danburzo suggests adding the following filter, which corrected the issue for me.

```
<?php
  add_filter( 'nav_menu_meta_box_object', array( $this, 'disable_pagination_in_menu_meta_box' ) );

  function disable_pagination_in_menu_meta_box($obj) {
    $obj->_default_query = array(
      'posts_per_page' => -1
    );
    return $obj;
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is annoying, I found that this happens only if the [Main Navigation] option is checked ,go to  menus on theme customization; uncheck this and you will be fine.

Answer (score -1):

The function you're looking for is [`wp_list_pages()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/).

Pay particular attention to these two arguments documented on that page.

- `depth` being the most relevant to your question.

  > 'depth' (int) Number of levels in the hierarchy of pages to include in
  >   the generated list. Accepts -1 (any depth), 0 (all pages), 1
  >   (top-level pages only), and n (pages to the given n depth). Default 0.
- There's also `child_of`, giving you the option to list only those that are children of a specific parent page that you have; i.e., a specific building's child pages.

  > 'child_of' (int) Display only the sub-pages of a single page by ID.
  >   Default 0 (all pages).

---

**Tip:** One more option is to use a combination of [`get_pages()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_pages/) and [`wp_list_pages()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/#comment-391) as shown by [example here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/#comment-391). Between the two, you should be able to display the hierarchy as desired.

Comment: Your example does work as expected for outputting the page hierarchy.  All of the pages appear nested as they should.  But how do I go about replacing the default admin nav-menu editor listing?  I messed around a bit with the depths in wp-admin/includes/class-walker-nav-menu-edit.php and class-walker-nav-menu-checklist.php to see if it would have any affect and no go (I know that wouldn't be a permanent solution.)